# C# Sitecore get inherited templates

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, sitecore

I'm trying to find all templates that inherit a particular template through code. I have the ID of the base template (`Base Web Page`), and I'm iterating through all of the template items in Sitecore looking for items that inherit `Base Web Page`.

```cs
foreach (var item in templateItems)
{
    var baseTemplates = item.Template.BaseTemplates.ToList();
    foreach (var baseTemplate in baseTemplates)
    {
        if (baseTemplate.ID == templateItem.ID)
        {
            inheritors.Add(item.ID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, `item.Template.BaseTemplates` gives me a list of the root level base templates; instead of giving me `Base Web Page`, it gives me the templates that `Base Web Page` inherits from (`Advanced`, `Appearance`, `Help`, etc)

[image]

Therefore I don't know if the item is actually inheriting `Base Web Page` or not.

Is there a method to get directly inherited templates? How can I find all templates that inherit `Base Web Page`?

Comment: Your solution lies in the LinkDatabase

Comment: care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part `item.Template` in the

```cs
var baseTemplates = item.Template.BaseTemplates.ToList();
```

line is incorrect.

`item.Template` returns `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template` here, so you're checking for a `BaseTemplate` of `Template` template always.

Your code should be:

```cs
foreach (var item in templateItems)
{
    var baseTemplates = new TemplateItem(item).BaseTemplates.ToList();
    foreach (var baseTemplate in baseTemplates)
    {
        if (baseTemplate.ID == templateItem.ID)
        {
            inheritors.Add(item.ID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And the better approach may be using `LinkDatabase` to find all the referrers of your item which link from `BaseTemplate` field like that:

```cs
var links = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(templateItem, false);
foreach (var link in links)
{
    if (link.SourceFieldID == Sitecore.FieldIDs.BaseTemplate)
    {
        inheritors.Add(link.SourceItemID.ToString());
    }
}
```